# Default Translator Language using Google Translate

Tags: html, internationalization, google-translate

I have a simple website that contains news from various parts of the world.  The news are sourced in their local language - so for example my website holds news data in Spanish, English, Italian, French, German.

Currently, the translation is handled by Google Translate API

I want the content to be read-able by the user on the site based on their language.  So if the user is English, all content should be translated to English.

The problem occurs with my website being default language in English, thus not allowing a translate language to English, which would convert all the non-english news to English.

Is there any workaround, my first thought was to make the language html tag null, but not sure of any other workarounds?

Comment: Can you please clarify whether you're using https://cloud.google.com/translate/ as you are saying or https://translate.google.com/manager/website/ which sounds like what you're actually using?

Comment: Sorry, big delay!

Solution was found - we embedded the Gooogle API at each text level and designated what the original text language was - since our text-positions on the website are fixed locations.

This allowed Google API to understand what it was translating from initially.